# Can you check if 3rd party cookie present / isset

Tags: cookies

I understand you cant read another sites cookies from a user, ie you cant read a users facebook cookie when they visit your site, but are you able to see if a facebook cookie is set / is present

ie. something like

```
if (//facebook cookie is set){
    echo "We see you use Facebook, would you like to login with it ?";
};`
```

Comment: [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not. Browsers are not supposed to leak any information about what they have done on other sites.